# catkin build question

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I have two catkin work directories and one is dependent on the other for a package. How do I tell the build to look there. Does it use ROS environment variable for a list of source directories? I did put source setup for both in my bashrc file. But the referring directory still does not find the package in the other ws.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261332/catkin-build-question/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2017-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sourcing both `setup.bash` files doesn't make both workspaces "active" -- as soon as you source the second, it negates the fact that you had sourced the first at all. Rather, you should be only sourcing the `setup.bash` file for the workspace that is an "overlay" on the first workspace. See [this answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/205976/sourcing-from-multiple-workspaces/?answer=205994#post-id-205994) for more explanation.

This is one of the reasons I really like `catkin-tools`; it features convenient commands for [explicit workspace chaining](http://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/verbs/catkin_config.html#explicitly-specifying-workspace-chaining).

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1